# SQLite3::SQLException: near "LIKE": syntax error: Can you use more than one OR in sqllite3?

Tags: sql, ruby, database, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to perform a search query in 4 different locations but when I run the query with more than one OR clause it gives me this error.

`SQLite3::SQLException: near "LIKE": syntax error: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "movies" WHERE (title LIKE '%Iron%' or rating LIKE '%Iron%' or cast LIKE '%Iron%')`

My current query looks like this.

`Movie.where('title LIKE ? or rating LIKE ? or cast LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%")`

If I limit it down to just the singular OR clause the page loads fine with no error so I am assuming that its just too many OR statements for the db to handle?

Answer (score 1):

`cast` is a keyword/reserved word (the name of a function to convert types).  Use escapes:

```
WHERE title LIKE '%Iron%' OR
      rating LIKE '%Iron%' OR
      "cast" LIKE '%Iron%'
```

Or, better yet, rename the column.

The list of reserved words is [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).